# regex find input value

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

The string is:

```
<input type="hidden" name="billing[address_id]" value="34543" id="billing:address_id" />
```

How can I get input value from this string?
I tried this code:

```
preg_match('/<input type="hidden" name="billing[address_id]" value="(.*?)" id="billing:address_id" \/>/mis', $html, $results);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is almost correct.. just escape the `[` and `]` at address_id.

```
preg_match('/<input type="hidden" name="billing\[address_id\]" value="(.*?)" id="billing:address_id" \/>/mis', $html, $results);
```